# unable to delete merge pull subscription

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication

Environment:
Merge pull subscription with anonymous subscribers, using web sync, publisher is 2008R2, subscribers are SQLEXPRESS 2008R2.

Issue:
I run sp_dropmergepullsubscription on subscriber and sp_dropmergesubscription on publisher, subscription is removed on subscriber, but why do I see an entry in sysmergesubscriptions on publisher, for that subscriber, with status 1 still?

I found a way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876913/sql-server-replication-removing-broken-subscriptions-at-the-publisher)
which suggests to manually delete entries, but why do I have to manually delete stuff?

Is it required to run sp_dropmergesubscription on publisher after running sp_dropmergepullsubscription on subscriber? Just deleting on subscription on subscriber side is not enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not manually delete the entries in sysmergesubscriptions.  Manually deleting these entries can result in not being able to add new subscribers down the road.

To delete a pull subscription to a Merge publication at the subscriber on the subscription database execute [sp_dropmergepullsubscription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187336.aspx).  Then at the publisher on the publication database execute [sp_dropmergesubscription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176045.aspx).  This is covered in [How to: Delete a Pull Subscription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146906.aspx).

Executing sp_dropmergesubscription at the publisher will not remove the entry from sysmergesubscription but will set the status to 2, which indicates it has been deleted.

If the status is still 1 in sysmergesubscriptions then perhaps you executed sp_dropmergesubscription incorrectly.  Make sure to specify @publication, @subscriber, and @subscriber_db.  Also, specify a value of pull for @subscription_type.

Comment: Thank you. Too late I deleted them manually. Before that, I did run the stored procedures correctly and no matter what it wouldn't set the status to 2 though the command runs successfully on the publisher side. Any thoughts?

Comment: I just noticed you have anonymous subscriptions.  Have you tried specifying @subscription_type of anonymous for sp_dropmergesubscription?

Comment: hm. no. I will try and let you know. btw, running the drop on publisher side is a must do step2 or the subscription removal process?

Comment: Yes.  Need to run sp_dropmergepullsubscription on the Subscriber then sp_dropmergesubscription on the Publisher.

Comment: "Manually deleting these entries can result in not being able to add new subscribers down the road". Hm. I just did that.. can you please elaborate on this? How is this going to screw me later? Is there anything I can do now to remedy what I did?

Comment: It might have worked since you are using anonymous subscriptions. Strictly speaking, directly editing system tables leaves you in an unsupported state and is not recommended.

Comment: i also tried everything with no luck. i set Status=2 in sysmergesubsciptions for the subscription, which allowed me to recreate it (same name but now Status=0).  i am using the sub, but I imagine you could delete it normally through SSMS after doing these steps.

Comment: Nice! 10 years later and a little more wiser, I no longer shy away from editing system tables, especially if that's what's required to solve a possibly tragic situation. It's nice to hear that there is someone else besides me still using Merge replication today.